# Why "mir gefallen" instead of "ich liebe"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Why do we use "mir gefallen" instead of "ich liebe"?

The sentences are:

> Mir hat die alte Wohnung besser gefallen.
>
> Ich liebe die alte Wohnung mehr

Which one of two is correct?
Why do we use "mir gefallen"?

Comment: Why do you say „I like the old flat“ vs. „I love the old flat“. And „besser“ only comes with gefallen, the right adverb for „lieben“ is „mehr“...

Comment: i am confused with the usage of mir gefallen as compared to ich liebe

Comment: What does your favorite dictionary say about the difference?

Comment: also, the second sentence is gramatically wrong. You can't use "besser" (better) with "lieben"(to love), you need to use "mehr" (more). This happens to be the same with english

Comment: Or in other words: speakers of English tend to use the verb "to love" excessively for any kind of positive attitude towards everything (food, weather, arts...). Users of other languages (e.g. German) use the equivalent verbs ("lieben") in the narrower sense of love between people. - There are some tendencies to be observed also in German to abuse "lieben" for other positive attitudes; this can best be understood as a contamination coming from all-dominating American popular culture and marketing.

Comment: @Hobbamok, this is wrong. First, whether _besser_ fits with _lieben_ is not a matter of grammar, but of semantics. Second, there are cases in which both fit, e.g., *"Mein neuer Freund kann besser lieben als mein Ex."*

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich and in this case the meaning is quite different. "Mehr lieben" means to like it more, while "besser lieben" means he is better at the act of loving. "Besser lieben" would usually be used to compare two people, where one shows a "better kind" of affection than the other. - or like in your example as an euphemism "lieben" like "making love" for sexual intercourse.

Comment: @Falco, that's right.

Comment: It paints a different picture. The old apartment fell better into my taste. Instead of my taste being an active agent it is the apartment which does the activity of falling here.

Answer (score 17):

**Remark:** The question was changed on June 22<sup>nd</sup>, 2019. Previously, the first example sentence was

> Mir hat die alte Wohnung *mehr* gefallen.

---

#### gefallen versus lieben

The verb [*gefallen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gefallen) is used to express that something pleases you, i. e., that you simply like it. The verb [*lieben*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lieben) expresses a strong affection, typically between lovers. Even though you may find *lieben* also in reference for things, it is used rather reluctantly there, for it would sound melodramatic.

#### gefallen ⇆ to like

> Mir hat die alte Wohnung *besser gefallen*.
>   
>   ⇆ I *liked* the former appartment *more*.

Notice that in German *besser gefallen* is more idiomatic than *mehr gefallen*. In English the opposite is true, i. e., *to like more* is more idiomatic than *to like better*.

Moreover, the roles of the subject and the object are reversed. While in German the subject is the thing that is liked and the object is the person who likes the thing, in English it is the other way round:

> Mir<sub>(object)</sub> gefällt<sub>(verb)</sub> die Wohnung<sub>(subject)</sub>.
>   
>   ⇆ I<sub>(subject)</sub> like<sub>(verb)</sub> the appartment<sub>(object)</sub>.

#### lieben ⇆ to love

> Ich liebe die alte Wohnung <s>besser</s> mehr.
>   
>   ⇆ I love the former appartment more.

Here, *mehr lieben* is more idiomatic than *besser lieben*, similar to English *love more* rather than *love better*.

Furthermore, the roles of subject and object remain the same when translating:

> Ich<sub>(subject)</sub> liebe<sub>(verb)</sub> die Wohnung<sub>(object)</sub>.
>   
>   ⇆ I<sub>(subject)</sub> love<sub>(verb)</sub> the appartment<sub>(object)</sub>.

Comment: "...for [lieben] would sound pathetic." - What would you say colloquially, that's the equivalent of the use of "love" in English, in this example?  (Or, "I love ice cream", "I love this park", etc.)

Comment: @BruceWayne, see Christian Geiselmann's comment below the question.

Comment: "pathetic" is a deceitfully false friend: It means "induces pity", *armselig*. You probably wanted to express the German *pathetisch*, perhaps as "lofty", "pompous" or "melodramatic". I find it not that easy to translate. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, vielen herzlichen Dank für diesen wichtigen Hinweis und die Korrektur. Man lernt nie aus!

Answer (score 13):

*Liebe* is a strong feeling in German and so is the action *lieben*. Much of German speakers' impression of U.S. Americans being superficial comes from their excessive use of *to love*.

McDonald's had no scruple translating their catch phrase in verbatim.

> I'm lovin it. — Ich liebe es.

Only an U.S. company can get away with that. Don't try it at home.

---

Instead of *lieben*, German speakers prefer other verbs for non-passionate love, most common are *mögen* and *gefallen*.

> Ich mag die neue Wohnung.

Puzzling, if you want to say you like the old flat better, it's:

> Aber ich mag die alte Wohnung *lieber*. *(not besser!)*

*Lieber* as an adjective in comparative is common for some odd reason. It's still some affection you signal in regards to the old flat. Its cozyness, being your home for years. Something like that.

With inanimate stuff, German speakers prefer *gefallen*:

> Mir gefällt unsere jetzige Wohnung besser. *(not lieber!)*

*Our current flat appeals better to me.*

*Unsere jetzige Wohnung* is the subject, which gives *mir* an appeal. *Mir* is *ich* in dative case because *ich* becomes the receiver of something – the appeal.

Comment: Actually, there was a slogan in the 68er student's protests movement which went something similar as _Wie kann ich noch sagen: "Ich liebe Dich!", seitdem ich weiß "Autos lieben Shell!"?_

Comment: Edeka behauptet, Lebensmittel zu lieben.

Comment: Die behaupten auch, Papis seien doof. Werbeagentur *Alt und matt* oder so …

Answer (score 1):

Both verbs have in common that they are used to express positive emotions.

However "gefallen" refers in general more to properties or outcomes of an event. Here you use it to express something that has happened has fullfilled your expectations.

For example:

> Mir gefällt es zu studieren.

*I like to study*. Here you would mean that the study program (or studying itself) fullfiled your expectations and you don't regret it.

You can see that in the other answers as well, almost all citations with "gefallen" refer to something *new* or *old*.

Also it is almost always used to describe emotions for *things*.

> Mir gefällt dein Haustier.

*I like your pet.*

This would sound a bit distant, here we would at least say *Ich mag dein Haustier*.

As already said "lieben" is used to show a strong feeling of true and deep love (*Ich liebe meinen Bruder*). It is almost exclusively used for people or at least pets (hence something that is or was alive).